# Cannot load/scroll full pdf in swift WebView.

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am trying to load a pdf using web view using swift.  It can load only one page of the pdf, cannot scroll down more than one page. What can i do?

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var webViews: UIWebView!

var path = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    path  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ibook", ofType: "pdf")!
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)

    /*webViews.scalesPageToFit = true
    webViews.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    webViews.userInteractionEnabled = true*/

    webViews.delegate = self

    self.webViews.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!
        ))
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


func webViewDidStartLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
    //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    println("webViewDidStartLoad")
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
    //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = [enter image description here][1]false
    webViews.scalesPageToFit = true
    webViews.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    webViews.userInteractionEnabled = true
    println("webViewDidFinishLoad")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped into the similar problem while trying to display external pdf (not the bundled one), but I suppose you can use the same fix.

In your `webViewDidFinishLoad`, check if the url is actually a pdf one. Because in my case I know what I'm expecting, I used simple dumb checking. If url links to a pdf, you need to reload the web view to show it correctly and hence be able to scroll.

Here is a bit simplified code in objective C. It should be quite similar in Swift. Try something like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    static BOOL isPdfReloaded = NO;

    if (!isPdfReloaded && [webView.request.URL.absoluteString containsString:@".pdf"])
    {
        [webView reload];
        isPdfReloaded = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        isPdfReloaded = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best solution is to migrate from UIWebView to WkWebView